# O que significa "ico" na palavra quântico?

Tags: significado, uso-de-palavras

Teria esse "ico" sentido relacionado a ícone?

Ícone não é uma imagem relacionada a alguma coisa, a qual queremos demonstrar com uma imagem?

Seria a descrição do ícone da quantia referida?

Quântico vem de quantidade?

Tem algum sentido relacionado a pequetico, que algumas pessoas usam para referir-se a algo pequeno, como um menino ou um filhote de animal?

Quântica seria também relacionada a "pequetica"? O que seria o "ica" nesse caso diferente do "ico"?

O radical de ícone é "ic" ou "ico"?

Poderias também explicar o significado de quântico/quântica, e quando podemos usar os termos, mesmo significados que não se usa habitualmente? Porque parece uma palavra a qual podemos usar para um certo tipo de coisas minúsculas, mas não sei quais.

Comment: Eu sugiro que você poste a pergunta sobre o radical de "ícone" separadamente, para que essa postagem fique mais focada.

Answer (score 3):

O sufixo "*ico*" denota apenas que se trata de um adjetivo. Vide, e.g., a [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/-ico), o [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/-ico) ou o [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/-ico):

> **-ico**²
> sufixo nominal de origem latina que ocorre sobretudo em adjetivos e exprime a ideia de semelhança, presença (cilíndrico; rômbico; alcoólico; iódico)
> **-ico²**
> (prefixo latino -icus, -a, -um, do grego -ikós, -ê, -ón)
> sufixo
> Indica relação, geralmente na formação de .adjetivos (ex.: fotográfico; medúsico).
> **-ico²**
> forma adjetivos de pertinência, referência: aeróbico, biológico, metálico, típico
> [F.: Do lat. -îcus, a, um, deriv. do gr. -ikós, é, ón]

"Quântico" significa:

> relacionado à [mecânica quântica](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mec%C3%A2nica_qu%C3%A2ntica),

que é um ramo fundamental da física, que descreve

> sistemas físicos cujas dimensões são próximas ou abaixo da escala atômica, tais como moléculas, átomos, elétrons, prótons e de outras partículas subatômicas, muito embora também possa descrever fenômenos macroscópicos em diversos casos.

Ou seja, não tem relação com "ícone". E, sim, sua etimologia tem relação com quantidade, dado que deriva de "[quanta](https://dicionario.priberam.org/quanta)":

> ***quanta*** |quânta|
> (palavra latina, plural de quantum, -i, que quantidade)
> ***quantum*** |quântu-m|
> (palavra latina que significa "que quantidade")
> [Física]  Quantidade mínima de energia que pode ser emitida, propagada ou absorvida.

Vale notar que os dicionários frequentemente definem "quântico" [como](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/qu%C3%A2ntico) "[FÍSICA] relativo à teoria dos quanta", mas essa é apenas a origem histórica do adjetivo, uma accepção muito restrita que não corresponde ao uso atual do termo (relacionado, como dito acima, à toda a física quântica).

Algumas expressões relacionadas podem ser encontradas fora do domínio técnico, com maior ou menor fidelidade ao significado original. "Salto quântico", por exemplo, denota uma mudança abrupta, que não passa por estados intermediários. Essa mudança pode ser arbitrariamente pequena, mas é comum vê-la usada significando um "grande salto".
Quanto a usar como significando "pequeno", acho que nunca vi - nem recomendaria.

Comment: Não sei se o sufixo -*ico*  e *ícone* não terão a mesma origem, lá no indoeuropeu ou coisa assim; em grego são iguais (talvez dependa das declinações, não sei), e *icone* em grego tinha uma carrada de signgificados, incluindo ’semelhança’; embora -*ico* raramente indique exatamente semelhança.

Comment: @Jacinto Entendo, parece mesmo uma possibilidade, mas acho que não vou incluir na resposta, pois prefiro dar mais ênfase à semântica que à etimologia aqui.